# Unable to run Pyschopy

Tags: python, macos

I am trying to run Python scripts for a Brain Computer Interface Paradigm that uses Psychopy as GUI to create a visual stimuli. I am using Mac OS and the scripts are tun through the terminal I get the following message:
"This program needs access to the screen. Please run with a
Framework build of python, and only when you are logged in
on the main display of your Mac."

I am using Python 2.7 and latest version of Psychopy (http://www.psychopy.org/).

Please let me know why is this issue coming. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Have you tried using `WxPython`/`PythonW`?

Comment: I have tried running scripts using pythonw instead of python and it opens up the Psychopy GUI to enter some initial data… Once I enter those, following message gets displayed on my terminal : "2017-08-10 16:44:12.166 python[52381:2593862] ApplePersistenceIgnoreState: Existing state will not be touched. New state will be written to /var/folders/cs/_c0k8l3j6m771s2pjk_fj0280000gn/T/com.continuum.python.savedState
/dev/tty.usbserial-DQ007Z1Y
hello_1.csv
/dev/tty.usbserial-DQ007Z1Y
<type ‘str’>
10.0
<type ‘float’>
60.4073238211" Gui of Psychopy still does not display anything.